# Leap Seconds on Android

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, clock, date-and-time

A leap second was recently added on June 30, 2015 23:59:60 UTC.

How are leap seconds implemented on Android (specifically Lollipop)?

Comment: Are you asking theoretically? If your phone receives its time automatically, it should be AFN (all fine now). If not, it's at most 1 second off additionally from your last manual time setting. Perhaps you should get on that, then.

Answer (score 2):

The leap second was not implemented in Lollipop or any other Android version. If you are really concerned with having 'atomic clock' accuracy, use [ClockSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.org.amip.ClockSync&hl=en), which synchronizes your device's clock with an atomic clock.

If you have root access, this is done automatically. Without root, a countdown assists in you manually synchronizing your clock. That will get you the one second back if you don't have network-provided time.

Comment: How does ClockSync show the leap second?  Does it properly show the right time on both the last second of the year, and the first second of the next year?  In particular, does it properly show the 61th second, e.g. `Sat Dec 31 23:59:60 UTC 2016`?

Answer (score 1):

In Date/Hour Settings page you have a checkbox to enable auto-checking time by the network.

I think it's your mobile operator that gives time. Then the mobile is always up-to-date (time speaking).

I don't think leap seconds are implemented in stock Android if we're not connected on any network.

Comment: On my phone, selecting "use network provided values" winds up being equal to "use GPS values"and it turns out GPS time is ahead of UTC by 17 seconds because GPS time doesn't have leap seconds.  So... what is the fix for this?

Comment: @Michael First time I heard of that.. Are you on Android Lollipop?

Comment: @Michael It looks like you're running in to a device-specific time reporting bug which is discussed here (though it should be reported to the device manufacturer): https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5485